# Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. 81.8 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-waf

I would like to ask for help about Elastic Beanstalk error:

**Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. 81.8 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx.**

I read some articles here and I followed the solution with WAF, so I created ACL which is assigned to our CloudFront, then I created the rule, which blocks all
requests which contain word HEAD in HTTP Method. When I try to send HEAD request from postman, then it works like I want (I receive error 403), but unfortunately the error still
exists and I see a lot of HEAD requests in the apache logs every day.

List of requests:

> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:09 +0000] "HEAD /mysql/dbadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:11 +0000] "HEAD /mysql/mysqlmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404
>   260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:11 +0000] "HEAD /phpMyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:11 +0000] "HEAD /phpmyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:12 +0000] "HEAD /phpmyadmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:13 +0000] "HEAD /2phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:13 +0000] "HEAD /phppma/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:14 +0000] "HEAD /shopdb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:15 +0000] "HEAD /program/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:15 +0000] "HEAD /dbadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:16 +0000] "HEAD /db/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:16 +0000] "HEAD /mysql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:17 +0000] "HEAD /db/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:17 +0000] "HEAD /sqlmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:18 +0000] "HEAD /php-myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:19 +0000] "HEAD /mysqladmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:19 +0000] "HEAD /admin/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404
>   260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:20 +0000] "HEAD /admin/sysadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:20 +0000] "HEAD /admin/db/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:21 +0000] "HEAD /admin/pMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:22 +0000] "HEAD /mysql/db/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:23 +0000] "HEAD /mysql/pMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:24 +0000] "HEAD /sql/php-myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:24 +0000] "HEAD /sql/sql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:25 +0000] "HEAD /sql/webadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:26 +0000] "HEAD /sql/websql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:30 +0000] "HEAD /sql/sqladmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:30 +0000] "HEAD /sql/phpmyadmin2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:31 +0000] "HEAD /sql/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:38 +0000] "HEAD /db/webadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:43 +0000] "HEAD /db/websql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:49 +0000] "HEAD /db/dbadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:49 +0000] "HEAD /db/phpmyadmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:51 +0000] "HEAD /db/phpMyAdmin-3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:52 +0000] "HEAD /administrator/phpMyAdmin/
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:52 +0000] "HEAD /administrator/web/ HTTP/1.1" 404
>   260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:54 +0000] "HEAD /administrator/PMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404
>   260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:54 +0000] "HEAD /phpMyAdmin2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:55 +0000] "HEAD /phpMyAdmin4/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:55 +0000] "HEAD /php-my-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:56 +0000] "HEAD /PMA2012/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:56 +0000] "HEAD /PMA2014/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:57 +0000] "HEAD /PMA2016/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:57 +0000] "HEAD /PMA2018/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:58 +0000] "HEAD /pma2012/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:42:59 +0000] "HEAD /pma2014/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:43:00 +0000] "HEAD /pma2016/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:43:01 +0000] "HEAD /pma2018/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:43:01 +0000] "HEAD /phpmyadmin2012/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:43:02 +0000] "HEAD /phpmyadmin2014/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:43:02 +0000] "HEAD /phpmyadmin2016/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
>
> [01/Aug/2017:07:43:04 +0000] "HEAD /phpmyadmin2018/ HTTP/1.1" 404 260
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I contacted direct AWS Support and this is the solution which they provided to me:

> I looked at the logs that you posted in case, I found that the agent
>   is Jorgee, which is a common malware agent. I came across the blog
>   regarding to this agent [1], though it is not official one but got
>   insights of it.
>
> A daemon named "healthd" in Elastic Beanstalk environment instances
>   monitor health by watching special log files. If the agent find lots
>   of 4xx in this file, the environment go to Severe state.
>
> `$ sudo tail /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2017-08-21-07
>   1503299631.249"/asdf"404"0.075"0.075"-
>   1503299631.379"/asdf"404"0.002"0.002"-`
>
> I see you have environments launched with the solution stack "64bit
>   Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.7.2 running Docker 17.03.1-ce", thus I would
>   like to provide a workaround of this issue for this solution stack.
>
> In the solution stack "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.7.2 running
>   Docker 17.03.1-ce", log format above is defined in
>   "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf", and enabled in
>   "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf".
>
> Therefore, you could configure nginx in your environments to ignore
>   requests which HTTP status is 404 or 403. Please try to add following
>   config file under .ebextensions directory of your application source
>   code bundle.
>
> **.ebextensions/healthd_ignore_4xx.config**
>
> ```
>    files:
>    "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf":
>    mode: "000644"
>    owner: root
>    group: root
>    content: |
>      # modification No.1
>       map $status $logflag {
>           404 0;
>           403 0;
>           default 1;
>       }
>
>       map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
>           default        "upgrade";
>           ""            "";
>       }
>
>       server {
>           listen 80;
>
>           gzip on;
>               gzip_comp_level 4;
>               gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
>
>           if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
>               set $year $1;
>               set $month $2;
>               set $day $3;
>               set $hour $4;
>           }
>
>           # modification No.2
>           # access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
>             access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd if=$logflag;
>
>           access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;
>
>           location / {
>               proxy_pass            http://docker;
>               proxy_http_version    1.1;
>
>               proxy_set_header    Connection            $connection_upgrade;
>               proxy_set_header    Upgrade                $http_upgrade;
>               proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
>               proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
>               proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>           }
>       }
> ```
>
> This config will replace default
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf file
>   with the content you defined. Modifications I made are:
>
> - No.1: added map directive which maps from $status to $logflag. when the request is 404 or 403, set $logflag to 0. set 1 for other status.
> - No.2: added if=$logflag in access_log [2] directive. Write to healthd monitoring logs only when the HTTP status is not 404 or 403.
>
> After you deploy the new version application with ebextensions config
>   above, your environment status will not be affected by invalid 404 or
>   403 requests.
>
> **References [1]:**
>   http://www.skepticism.us/2015/05/new-malware-user-agent-value-jorgee/
>   **[2]**:
>   http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_log_module.html#access_log

Answer (score 2):

For me, I didn't have a Response for the root(`/`) so by simply adding a dummy page in spring-boot my problem with ELB went away.

```
@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String sayHello() {
    return "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue,

I changed the elasticbeans load balancer to application level one and enabled WAF integration.

In WAF, I defined following rules to prevent malware requests.

```
 URI contains: "/pma" after converting to lowercase.
 URI contains: "/sql" after converting to lowercase.
 URI contains: "/admin" after converting to lowercase.
 URI ends with: "php" after converting to lowercase.
 URI contains: "/mysql" after converting to lowercase.
 URI contains: "/db" after converting to lowercase.
 URI contains: "/2phpmyadmin/ " after converting to lowercase.
 URI contains: "/shopdb/ " after converting to lowercase.
 URI contains: "/php" after converting to lowercase.
```